# Implementing "Guess the number" game

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my first post in StackOverFlow and I'm sure that I can find for 100% percent an answer for it, but I'd really like to start my adventure with programming and know that this community might help me with it.

My questions are:

1. I wrote that first piece of code but I'd like to add here a function where the user writes the guess number bigger than the first one.
2. I am troubled with adding the additional function `if` for this situation - I do understand that it wouldn't suppose to be `if`, but `elif`.

Is anyone has any idea how to suppose to look-alike??

```
import random
top_range = input("Write a number bigger then 0: ")
if top_range.isdigit() or top_range[0] == "-":
    top_range = int(top_range)
    if top_range <= 0:
        print('Write a number bigger then 0')
        quit()
else:
    print('Write a number bot a word')
    quit()
    random_number = random.randint(0, top_range)
guesses = 0
while True:
    guesses += 1
    user_guess = input("Guess the number : ")
    if user_guess.isdigit():
            user_guess = int(user_guess)
    else:
        print('Write another number.')
        continue
    if user_guess == random_number:
        print('You did it!')
        break
    else:
        if user_guess < random_number:
          print('The number is bigger then that')
        else:
          print('The number is smaller than that')
print('You did it in', guesses, "guesses!")
```

Comment: You lost me there. You know that you can find answers for your question but you ask it anyway to know that the community helps you? Is this a test of the community? SMH

Comment: That is unclear what you want, I don't get it, could you try to clarify ? Maybe specify the part of the code where the change should be, I don't get if that should at the initial number input, or in the game itself later

Comment: what does ''*add here a function where the user writes the guess number bigger than the first one.*'' mean? i don't understand your request, could you gently explain it to us, so we can help more?

Comment: I do apologise if I wasn't been so clear. What I meant was that there the flow of this looks like that: Player input a number, then guessing the other random one, which is between 0 and "top_range". They're missing a block where the user is writing as a guess bigger number than the top_range. After the user receives the information "Your number is bigger than a top_range.

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) *and* [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a first if, then use `elif` for the other choices. I've also simplify a bit the first if

```
while True:
    guesses += 1
    user_guess = input("Guess the number : ")
    if not user_guess.isdigit():
        print('Write another number.')
        continue

    user_guess = int(user_guess)

    if user_guess > top_range:
        print("That is higher than top range, try again")
    elif user_guess == random_number:
        print('You did it!')
        break
    elif user_guess < random_number:
        print('The number is bigger then that, try again')
    else:
        print('The number is smaller than that, try again')
```